# Mongoose Update error $isSingleNested

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error on update

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property '$isSingleNested' of undefined]
```

I used the same code many many times now this is making problem

```
return Ticket.update({
               "id": value.id
              }, {
                    $set: value
          })
```

Any one knows what is the problem ?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4418

Comment: how does `value` object look like?

Answer (score 0):

you cant set `value` directly. you need to set `value` to some `field`. you need to provide the `field name` to which you need to set the `value`.

Try this:

```
return Ticket.update({
           "id": value.id
          }, {
                $set: { "someFieldName": value}
      })
```

Don't forget to replace `someFieldName` to the `field` name to which you want to set that `value`.

If you need to set multiple values, separate different fields using `comma(,)`.